# How do I write Selenium variables to a text file?

Tags: c#

I'm automating a web application and for finishing the tests I want to print the values generated during the process to a text file. I'm not so clear in how to accomplish this, I have printed the variable in the name of the file successfully. However the text inside the file is not being printed.

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Convert.ToString(vars["Variable1"]) + ".txt", true))
            {

                writer.WriteLine(today); //Today Date//
                writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 1: ", vars["Variable1"].ToString());
                writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 2: ", vars["Variable2"].ToString());
                writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 3: ", vars["Variable3"].ToString());
                writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 4: ", vars["Variable4"].ToString());


            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest doing this with Json.

Can be done easily like so:

```
// At the top before the class declaration
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Convert.ToString(vars["Variable1"]) + ".txt", true))
{

    writer.WriteLine(today); //Today Date//
    writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 1: ", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vars["Variable1"]));
    writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 2: ", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vars["Variable2"]));
    writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 3: ", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vars["Variable3"]));
    writer.WriteLine("Generated Info 4: ", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vars["Variable4"]));


}
```

Let me know if there are any problems with using the solution.

If you don't want to use Json, you can override the ToString method of your variables to print out the inner values when you call .ToString() on an object, but this is the lazier way.

Comment: Used both methods as you told me and finally it worked!, thanks so much!

Also this one worked!
writer.WriteLine("Variable 5: " + vars["Variable5"].ToString());